# remove special characters in an array in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have an array as shown below:

```
[
  [
    "[\"\", \"Mrs. Brain Bauch\", \"Vernice Ledner\"]", 
    "[\"\", \"Robb Ratke\", \"Amaya Jakubowski\"]",       
    "[\"\", \"Lindsey Cremin III\", \"Harvey Fisher\"]", 
    "[\"\", \"Daniela Schneider\", \"Benny Schumm\"]"
  ]
]
```

How can I convert this into the array structure shown below:

```
[
  [
    ["Mrs. Brain Bauch", "Vernice Ledner"], 
    ["Robb Ratke", "Amaya Jakubowski"],       
    ["Lindsey Cremin III", "Harvey Fisher"], 
    ["Daniela Schneider", "Benny Schumm"]
  ]
]
```

Comment: The outer [] results in an array of 1.  Was that your intention?

Comment: You see some trailing slashes one first sample code but the real thing is it outputs array with your second sample code.

Comment: Is there any way you could persuade the producer of this data (is it you?) to use a much simpler method of data serialization such as YAML or JSON?  Having to parse these strings is a lot more work and makes your code more complex than it needs to be.  If you haven't already looked at YAML or JSON, I highly recommend that you do.  They're trivially simple to use.

Comment: @borderline end result that i want is to remove all the trailing characters present in my first array so that i get my resultant second array.

Comment: @KeithBennett This data is produced by me . I have retrieved this data from my database through activerecord. Active record returns the  query result set to me in this format. So i Think that way json or yaml wont work for me.

Comment: @AhkshaeyRavi how do you retrieve this data exactly? Could you show the code, please? This seems to be a [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377).

Comment: ActiveRecord returns data in the form of objects.  If you are getting the string representation of a nested array, then there must be something you have done to make it that way.  You will be much happier if you address this, rather than wasting your time and energy parsing this inappropriate representation.

Comment: What did I say? Good move!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
require 'json'
input = [[
  "[\"\", \"Mrs. Brain Bauch\", \"Vernice Ledner\"]", 
  "[\"\", \"Robb Ratke\", \"Amaya Jakubowski\"]",       
  "[\"\", \"Lindsey Cremin III\", \"Harvey Fisher\"]", 
  "[\"\", \"Daniela Schneider\", \"Benny Schumm\"]"
]]
[input.first.map { |l| JSON.parse l }.map { |a| a.reject &:empty? }]
#⇒ [[
#    ["Mrs. Brain Bauch", "Vernice Ledner"], 
#    ["Robb Ratke", "Amaya Jakubowski"],       
#    ["Lindsey Cremin III", "Harvey Fisher"], 
#    ["Daniela Schneider", "Benny Schumm"]
#  ]]
```

Comment: Better than mine! Note there is one more level of array nesting. btw, do you need `require 'json'` with Rails?

Comment: No, with Rails `require 'json'` is not necessary, but I will add it anyway, thx.

Comment: @mudasobwa  This too worked for me. Since this is a better implementation I am accepting this as my answer

Comment: It is by no means “a better” implementation. What is significant, that this approach uses the `JSON.parse`, which is always safer and more reliable than regular expressions.

Answer (score 5):

If `arr` is your array:

```
r = /
    (?<=\")    # match `\"` in a positive lookbehind
    [A-Z]      # match a capital letter
    [a-z\.\s]+ # match a letter, period or space one or more times
   /ix         # case-insenitive (i) and free-spacing (x) regex definition  modes

[arr.first.map { |s| s.scan r }]
  #=> [[["Mrs. Brain Bauch", "Vernice Ledner"],
  #     ["Robb Ratke", "Amaya Jakubowski"],
  #     ["Lindsey Cremin III", "Harvey Fisher"],
  #     ["Daniela Schneider", "Benny Schumm"]]]
```

Comment: Ahkshaey, I'm glad you found this helpful, but I am dismayed. You selected my answer a mere 20 minutes after you posted the question. That may discourage other answers, which might be better or just interesting, and if some readers are still working on answers you should give them time to post. My advice is to remove the greenie for now, and wait for at least a couple of hours before making a selection.